# Decay of an inverse fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

For the following function:
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-\hat{f}(\omega)e^{-|\omega|y}}{1+|\omega|}e^{i\omega x}d\omega
$$

can we conclude that $u\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$? Here, $y>0$ and $f$ is a compactly supported smooth function.

If the terms multiplying $\hat{f}$ were smooth, I think I could argue that the integrand is Schwartz because $\hat{f}$ is Schwartz and the FT preserves that property, and then use the same reasoning to conclude that $u$ decayed at infinity. But unless I'm mistaken, the terms with $|\omega|$ aren't differentiable at $\omega=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform of any $L^1$ function [decays at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). Is the function 
$$g(\omega) = \frac{-\hat{f}(\omega)e^{-|\omega|y}}{1+|\omega|}$$
in $L^1$? Yes, it is, for a number of reasons. Even the boundedness of $\hat f$ is enough here, thanks to the exponential term $e^{-|\omega|y}$. Or, even neglecting the exponential term, just having $f\in L^2$ is enough,  since the product 
$$\hat{f}(\omega) \frac{1}{1+|\omega|}$$
is integrable by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (both terms are in $L^2$).